# Can't access to send_tokens function in erc20token-sdk-python library

Tags: ether, erc-20, python

I created the contract and trying to connect to ethereum mainnet using "erc20token-sdk-python" library. When I am trying to send tokens from one address to another it is showing "ValueError: No matching functions found". What am I doing wrong?

```
import erc20token
import json
contract_abi = '[{"constant": "True","inputs": [],"name": "name","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "string"}],"payable": "False","type": "function"},{"constant": "True","inputs": [],"name": "decimals","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "uint8"}],"payable": "False","type": "function"},{"constant": "True","inputs": [{"name": "_owner","type": "address"}],"name": "balanceOf","outputs": [{"name": "balance","type": "uint256"}],"payable": "False","type": "function"},{"constant": "True","inputs": [],"name": "symbol","outputs": [{"name": "","type": "string"}],"payable": "False","type": "function"}]'

token_sdk = erc20token.SDK(provider_endpoint_uri='https://mainnet.infura.io/12345678',
                           private_key='private_key_here',
                           contract_address='0x818fc6c2ec5986bc6e2cbf00939d90556ab12ce5', 
                           contract_abi=json.loads(contract_abi),
                           gas_price=40, gas_limit=50000)
tx_id = token_sdk.send_tokens('address', 10)
print(tx_id)
```

Error logs:

```
  tx_id = token_sdk.send_tokens('0xbeb6f3FBA63E462fDA138c67b4ADbAd416859b8f', 10)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/erc20token/sdk.py", line 296, in send_tokens
    hex_data = self.token_contract._encode_transaction_data('transfer', args=(address, self.web3.toWei(amount, 'ether')))
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 734, in _encode_transaction_data
    fn_name, args, kwargs,
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 663, in _get_function_info
    fn_abi = cls._find_matching_fn_abi(fn_name, args, kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 627, in _find_matching_fn_abi
    raise ValueError("No matching functions found")
ValueError: No matching functions found
```

Comment: You might be interested in: https://github.com/carver/ethtoken.py as an example implementation (or to use directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ABI you're using seems to be missing the `transfer` function.

You can find the full ABI for the contract you're using here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x818fc6c2ec5986bc6e2cbf00939d90556ab12ce5#code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Will ABI be same for all the erc20tokens or will there be different ABI's for each erc20token?

Comment: Some part of the ABI has to be the same to conform to the ERC20 standard, but outside of that there could be differences. If you're just calling `transfer` (via `send_tokens` in Python), you should be fine to reuse the same ABI for every token.

Comment: Thaks, Got it. I want to test these transactions in testnet before deploying it to the production. How to do the testing and how can I see the transactions in the test etherscan? Could you please provide me docs so that I can follow those docs?

Comment: If you use a public test network, like Ropsten, then you can see those transactions on Etherscan: https://ropsten.etherscan.io.

Comment: I used that in the provider_endpoint_uri='https://ropsten.etherscan.io' in my code but giving "erc20token.exceptions.SdkConfigurationError: cannot connect to provider endpoint"

Comment: That's the link to Etherscan. Your provider is Infura. (And you'll need to find a token on Ropsten, perhaps by deploying one yourself.)